# Android draw path

Tags: android, performance, path, draw

It is not good idea to construct path object every time when call Draw method.
Is it better to keep path object and clear/set points every time?

Update:
One more question - what is difference between 'reset' and 'rewind' path object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is better to reset the path and set the points rather than instatiating a new one. This prevents excessive allocation of memory, which can lead to frequent garbage collection. When the GC runs the graphics may pause for a moment, especially on older devices so you want to keep this to a minimum.

The `reset()` and `rewind()` methods both have pretty much the same effect, except that `rewind()` [keeps the internal data structure intact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#rewind%28%29), which can improve performance particularly if your path always has the same number of points.

Comment: "if your path always has the same number of points" - this is key part!